# Integration on a polyhedral spherical cell

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $n\in \mathbb N\setminus\{0,1\}$, $E=\{\xi\in \mathbb R^{2n}\mid \xi_1=0\}$, $K\subset E$ be a $(2n-1)$-dimensional convex polyhedral cone with apex at the origin and $B\subset\mathbb R^{2n}$ the unit ball about the origin. If ${\rm vol}_{2n-1}(K\cap B)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $K\cap B$, I would like to know if the following equality is correct:

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{K\cap B}
\frac{\Vert \xi\Vert^2+\xi_2^2}{\Vert \xi\Vert^{n+1}}\,d\xi_2\wedge\ldots\wedge d\xi_{2n}
=2{\rm vol}_{2n-1}(K\cap B)\,.
\end{eqnarray}

The preceding formula is a consequence of some relations about *Kazarnovskii mixed pseudovolume* (a generalization of Minkowski mixed volume) but it seem to me it can hardly be true, at least in this generality.

My attempt to prove it uses spherical coordinates. Setting $d\vartheta=d\vartheta_1\wedge\ldots\wedge d\vartheta_{2n-2}$ and passing to polar coordinates in $E$ yields the equivalent relation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{K\cap B}
\rho^{n-1}[1+(\cos\vartheta_1)^2]\prod_{\ell=1}^{2n-3}(\sin\vartheta_\ell)^{2n-2-\ell} d\rho\wedge d\vartheta
=
2\int_{K\cap B}
\rho^{2n-2}\prod_{\ell=1}^{2n-3}(\sin\vartheta_\ell)^{2n-2-\ell} d\rho\wedge d\vartheta\,,
\end{eqnarray}
or, equivalently,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{K\cap\partial B}
\left[\frac{2-(\sin\vartheta_1)^2}{n}-\frac{2}{2n-1}\right](\sin\vartheta_1)^{2n-3}\prod_{\ell=2}^{2n-3}(\sin\vartheta_\ell)^{2n-2-\ell}d\vartheta
=
0\,.\label{integrale-lungo}
\end{eqnarray}
Since
\begin{eqnarray}
\left[\frac{2-(\sin\vartheta_1)^2}{n}-\frac{2}{2n-1}\right](\sin\vartheta_1)^{2n-3}d\vartheta_1
=
d \left[ \frac{(\sin\vartheta_1)^{2n-2}\cos\vartheta_1}{n(2n-1)}\right]
\,,
\end{eqnarray}
the last integral becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
&&
\int_{K\cap\partial B}
d \left[ \frac{(\sin\vartheta_1)^{2n-2}\cos\vartheta_1}{n(2n-1)}\cdot
\prod_{\ell=2}^{2n-3}(\sin\vartheta_\ell)^{2n-2-\ell}d\vartheta_2\wedge\ldots\wedge d\vartheta_{2n-2}\right]\\
&=&
\int_{\partial[K\cap\partial B]}
\frac{(\sin\vartheta_1)^{2n-1}\cos\vartheta_1}{n(2n-1)}
\prod_{\ell=2}^{2n-3}(\sin\vartheta_\ell)^{2n-2-\ell}d\vartheta_2\wedge\ldots\wedge d\vartheta_{2n-2}\,,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\partial[K\cap\partial B]$ is a $(2n-3)$-dimensional spherical chain obtained as the intersection of $\partial B$ with the relative boundary of $K$.
Now, $\partial[K\cap\partial B]$ is a finite union of hyperplane sections of $\partial B$. Even if one writes down the linear equations of each boundary piece in order to eliminate the variable $\vartheta_1$, the resulting integral is very nasty and I hardly imagine it can be zero!

Could anybody suggest a way out? Thank you in advance.